# AWS ECS Fargate container ordering with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I need to configure 2 containers within the same AWS Fargate task using AWS container ordering in order to control the order in which the containers start.

Is there a way to configure container ordering using Terraform while specifying the container name and condition?

Same way we do using `dependsOn` in task definition over AWS:

```
 "dependsOn": [    {
       "containerName": "foo",
       "condition": "START"    } ]
```

**More details**: Given 2 containers within the same Fargate task, I need to specify that one of the containers depends on the other one having already started. The code snippet shows the required configuration over AWS. I need the exact same configuration but using Terraform instead.

Here is what my configuration looks like :

```
      dummy-task = {
    tasks = {
      container-a= {
        port = 5000
      }
      container-b = {
        port            = 8080
         dependsOn = {
          container-a: "START"
        }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question's example to create a [mcve] please? It would also help if you explain what that example does and how it differs from what you want to happen.

Comment: I just updated my question with more details on the scenario that I haved in minds. I hope it is  clearer now.

Comment: Since you provide the container task definition in Terraform as RAW JSON that matches directly to the AWS parameters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html you would simply define the `dependsOn` field in the task definition JSON and let Amazon handle it as you describe in your question, instead of expecting Terraform to handle it.

Comment: What have you tried in Terraform because, as mentioned, the container definitions are just JSON in Terraform (and passed as a list of them to the task definition resource) so should be the same as you are used to from outside of Terraform.

Comment: I already tried passing the same configuration as json in my task definition over terraform, but it wan't working.

Comment: What wasn't working? Edit your question to include the Terraform code as a [mcve] and then explain what isn't working clearly. If it errors include the error output in full. If it doesn't do what you expect then explain what it is doing and how that differs from what you expect.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thank you for your comment. I just updated my question by including an example of my Terraform code. Regarding your other question, there are no errors. As I explained in my question, i want to setup container ordering and it's not working at all with no errors. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: That isn't a complete example. You might want to read the linked guide in [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You will be using `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource in Terraform, try specifying the 'dependsOn' in your json definition as usual:

```
container_definitions = "${file("task-definitions/service.json")}"
```

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html

Unless Terraform is doing something fancy, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In an [aws_ecs_task_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition), you can supply [dependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_dependson) in the container definition.

```
container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name        = "nginx"
      image       = "nginx"
      essential   = true
      dependsOn   = [{
        containerName = "nginx-config"
        condition     = "COMPLETE"
      }]
    },
    {
      name        = "nginx-config"
      image       = "bash"
      essential   = false
    }
])
```